# Create a Users model where previous Users model existed then dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am working on a Rails application where the previous developer had created a Users model, then later dropped it in lieu of another solution.  The migration files are still in the repository, but obviously the table doesn't exist. I am now trying to create a User authentication system to integrate a blog, but I am running into the issue of the previous migration and getting the following error message when trying `rails g model User`:

"Another migration is already named create_users..."

Is it possible  there a way to create Users again?

Just to be extra clear.  There is a create_users and later a drop_users migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. $ rails g model User --migration=false
2. $ rails g migration create_users_again
3. open create_users_again migration file (created in step 2), and define your table as:

  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.email :string 

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :email
  end
```

You can look your old create_users migration file for help.

Answer (score 1):

When the previous developer ran `rails g model user`, this created a migration class like so:

`class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Now that you are running `rails g model user`, Rails is complaining that that class `CreateUsers`, already exits.

You can either:

1. Rename the previous migration to `CreateUsersPrevious` (don't forget to rename the migration file as well xxxxxxxxxxx_create_users_previous.rb) if you would like to keep it documented in your migration history
2. Remove the old migration file